# Node.js SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: Nothing to repeat

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I know this is a duplicate question, sorry guys, but i've already read and tried out the solutions to similar questions here, but it doesn't seem to work (probably because i didn't really understand the problem).

I am making a discord dice-roll bot using Node.js for me and my friends to use when we play D&D. When searching for (dis)advantage in rolls, im making a RegExp, but when using `new RegExp(regExpString);`, Node gives me `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: Nothing to repeat`.

There doesn't seem to be a problem when i use a regular expression directly instead of creating one from a string, but that isn't that helpfull to me, because i build my regular expression using an array easily customizable valis words for advantage/disadvantage.

Here's the code:

```
const advantageWords = [
    "example",
    "list",
    "of",
    "valid",
    "words"
];

let advRegExp = "(+|-)? *[0-9]* *";

for (i in advantageWords) {
    if (i != 0)
        advRegExp += "|";
    advRegExp += advantageWords[i];
}

advRegExp += " *(+|-)? *[0-9]*";

let reg = new RegExp(advRegExp, "i");
```

I've seen things about double escaping backlashes, and even though i didn't quite get why, i tried doing it in a few different ways and it didn't help.

PS: im using Node.js 8.9.2

edit: the problem was with scaping the plus sign. "+" -> "\+"

Comment: You'll need to escape the plus sign, assuming you're matching a literal plus sign:  `"(\\+|-)? *[0-9]* *"`.  Don't know if that will solve your problem, though.

Comment: can you post an example of a "correct" regex that would be generated so we know what your code is supposed to output? and have you validated that that is a valid regex?

Comment: BTW, use `.join()`.

Comment: Just use `[+-]? *\d* *`. The `+` is a special character (quantifier)

Comment: When in doubt, test your RegExps: http://regex101.com/

Comment: the problem was with the plus sign. thanks guys, escaping it with \\ fixed everything